# why fileupload is not possible thru ajax

Tags: ajax, http, file-upload

I am trying to understand why fileupload doesnot work with ajax, there must be any way where i can upload file asynchron without refreshing the page. refreshing the page isnot always a wanted thing. Sometimes, what i need here is very much needed by others also, i saw many questions regarding this issue, i am just asking out of curiosity **what the reason can be why** fileupload cannot work in ajax.

can someone explain me please why and what the other options are?

thanks reading

Comment: Most use a hidden Iframe trick.

Comment: ask microsoft, maybe. they're the ones who came up with xmlhttprequest to begin with. probably because they only envisioned it as a method for requesting data from a server, not that it'd become a full-fledged bi-directional communications channel.

Comment: @doniyor: You might want to give more information on how it doesn't work. What file you're uploading, how did you do it, from where, to where, etc.